# remove nodes listed into XmlNodeList from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

I have a problem with my XML file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
    <settings>
     <excelFilePath>C:\Temp\</excelFilePath>
     <mailHost>smtp</mailHost>
     <mailPort>25</mailPort>
     <mailFrom>me@test.com</mailFrom>
     <keepInCopy>
         <mailCC>email1@test.com</mailCC>
         <mailCC>email2@test.com</mailCC>
         <mailCC>email3@test.com</mailCC>
    </keepInCopy>
    <mailSubject>My Mail subject</mailSubject>
    <mailBodyPath>Templates\Template1.htm</mailBodyPath>
    </settings>
 </config>
```

In practice I just need to delete all tags "mailCC".
I'm currently trying this C# code, but nothing happens:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(FilePath);

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("mailCC");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    xn.RemoveChild(xn.FirstChild);
    xml.Save(FilePath);
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Any reason you want to use XmlDocument rather than LINQ to XML? The latter makes this utterly trivial... (It doesn't help that you don't show us what `xmlTag` is, either...)

Comment: What is the value of `xmlTag`?

Comment: i have just updated my post with necessary information, xmlTag is the string  "mailCC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the node will update the collection, so you should not use a `foreach` loop.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("mailCC");

while (xnList.Count > 0) {
    xnList[0].ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnList[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `XmlDocument` a node is removed from it's parent. But you could also do :

```
var xn = xml.SelectSingleNode("/config/settings/keepInCopy");
if (xn != null)
{
    xn.RemoveAll(); // Remove all "mailCC" elements, but keep "keepInCopy" node **OR**
    xn.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xn); // Remove "keepInCopy" element and all children
}
```

Comment: got an error in foreach - The element list has changed. The enumeration operation failed to continue.

Comment: Please, try the other version